# The basic usage in the Graph-tool: how to delete vertex and related edges in the Graph-tool?

Tags: python, graph-tool

I am new to Graph-tool and learning the basic operation on the Graph. The below command confused me a lot.

```py
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> G=Graph(directed=False)
>>> from graph_tool.all import *                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
>>> G=Graph(directed=False)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
>>> G.add_vertex()                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
<Vertex object with index '0' at 0x7f70714a00f0>
>>> G.add_vertex()
<Vertex object with index '1' at 0x7f70714a0210>
>>> G.add_vertex()
<Vertex object with index '2' at 0x7f70714a00f0>
>>> G.add_vertex()
<Vertex object with index '3' at 0x7f70714a0210>
>>> G.add_vertex()
<Vertex object with index '4' at 0x7f70714a00f0>
>>> G.add_vertex()
<Vertex object with index '5' at 0x7f70714a0210>
>>> G.add_vertex()
<Vertex object with index '6' at 0x7f70714a00f0>
>>> G.add_edge(1,2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
<Edge object with source '1' and target '2' at 0x7f7085fca9d0>
>>> print(G)
<Graph object, undirected, with 7 vertices and 1 edge at 0x7f70967c5400>
>>> G.clear_vertex(1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
>>> print(G)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
<Graph object, undirected, with 7 vertices and 1 edge at 0x7f70967c5400>
>>> G.clear_vertex(2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
>>> print(G)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
<Graph object, undirected, with 7 vertices and 1 edge at 0x7f70967c5400>
```

I know the clear_vertex is to clear all edges related with the Vertex. But after executing the clear_vertex, it seems that the Graph still contains 1 edge created before. Will I need to revise my code ?

Thank you

Comment: I've run your code and got the same result, but if you call `G.get_edges()` you will get an empty array, so I'd say this is a bug in the string representation (which may or may not have deeper consequences).

Comment: what I worry is that I never used graph-tool before so I can not say I was right for this code. Thank you for the comment here for review. @jdehesa

Comment: I also saw that the G.clear_edges() doesn't work as well and the edges still existed in the print(G).

Comment: I think you are using the library correctly (it's been some time since I last used graph-tool, but this looks pretty straightforward). You may consider [submitting a bug report](https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/issues/) in order to get some feedback from the dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug, but I was already fixed a while ago in git:

https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/commit/12fea4983ab98eae410a446f27ae5c0dd34cd90c

The bug is mostly harmless, as it amounts simply to a failure in updating the edge counts when clearing vertices. The edges are in fact deleted.